# Subscribe to TFS2013 build and backlog events

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, backlog

I want to create a windows service that listens for TFS2013 events. I am particularly interested in events triggered by builds, e.g.: build started, build completed, and events triggered by changes to backlog items.
My questions are:

- Is this possible?
- Where can I find an SDK? (what assemblies do I need)
- Are there any recent examples?

All examples I found so far seem to be very dated…as in from 2010… They involve the usage of an ISubscriber interface that is supposed to be moved to another assembly since TFS2013 update 2.

Comment: Any problem with the examples from 2010?

Comment: Well I am not sure. As I am using the latest version of TFS I somewhat expected a newer API / technology to exist. Should I still be using WCF for this?

Comment: Yep, the TFS2010 WCF examples seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The content of this article has solved my issue:

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/how-to-use-wcf-to-subscribe-to-the-tfs-2010-event-service-rolling-up-hours.aspx